# Polygon symbology in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, symbology, basemap

I am working on a basemap project for pedestrians map for that I have a feature class for crosswalks (zebra crossing) as a polygon feature and I want a symbology of black white line as zebra crossing the problem is that if I am using a hatch line it is not working properly because the lines are oriented by screen not by the angle of polygons.

Is there is any way so that the symbology comes by angle of polygons?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to run the geoprocessing funcion *Minimum Bounding Geometry* with your polygon layer as the input.  If the checkbox for geometry characteristics is on, the output layer will have a field called *MBG_Orientation*.  You can use that field to determine the angle of hatching in the symbol for the zebra crossings.
[image]

Add a hatched symbology, click on the symbol to edit it and adjust the parameters as shown here:
[image]

Enter this expression:
[image]

Then you should get something like this:
[image]